# Server unable to send stored db data via email in android app

Tags: android, android-service, accelerometer, latitude-longitude, gyroscope

I have an application where the accelerometer/gyroscope/linear acceleration/
latitude/longitude readings are sent to the server to track the user.

This issue I am facing when the mobile device doesnt have internet connectivity, the 
data is saved in the local database.However, when the device comes in to network the
data is syncronized with server.As soon as the server receieve the readings the user's
position is tracked and the along with the readings the data(accelerometer/gyroscope/
linear acceleration/latitude/longitude readings) is sent to the user via e-mail in 
every 1 minute.This issue is being faced after the ice creame sandwich i.e. ANDROID-4 and above.
Also, when running the appication on DDMS getting this error.Please refer the below logcat file.

```
11-29 11:37:37.336: D/Vold(81): Volume sdcard state changing 3 (Checking) -> 4 (Mounted)
11-29 11:37:37.347: E/VoldConnector(250): NDC Command {114 volume mount /storage/sdcard0} took too long (3737ms)
11-29 11:37:37.375: W/ShutdownThread(250): Result code 0 from MountService.shutdown
11-29 11:37:37.715: D/MountService(250): sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNSHARED dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 (has extras) }
11-29 11:37:37.730: I/PackageManager(250): Updating external media status from unmounted to unmounted
11-29 11:37:37.730: D/MountService(250): volume state changed for /storage/sdcard0 (shared -> unmounted)
11-29 11:37:37.734: D/MountService(250): sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_UNMOUNTED dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 (has extras) }
11-29 11:37:37.734: I/StorageNotification(336): Media {/storage/sdcard0} state changed from {shared} -> {unmounted}
11-29 11:37:37.738: D/VoldCmdListener(81): volume shared /storage/sdcard0 ums
11-29 11:37:37.765: D/MountService(250): volume state changed for /storage/sdcard0 (unmounted -> checking)
11-29 11:37:37.769: D/MountService(250): sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_CHECKING dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 (has extras) }
11-29 11:37:37.820: I/ActivityManager(250): Start proc android.process.media for broadcast com.android.providers.media/.MediaScannerReceiver: pid=24156 uid=10024 gids={1015, 1023, 1024, 1028, 2001, 3003, 3007}
11-29 11:37:37.820: D/MountService(250): volume state changed for /storage/sdcard0 (checking -> mounted)
11-29 11:37:37.824: I/PackageManager(250): Updating external media status from unmounted to mounted
11-29 11:37:37.832: D/MountService(250): sendStorageIntent Intent { act=android.intent.action.MEDIA_MOUNTED dat=file:///storage/sdcard0 (has extras) }
11-29 11:37:37.863: D/VoldCmdListener(81): asec list
11-29 11:37:37.894: I/StorageNotification(336): Media {/storage/sdcard0} state changed from {unmounted} -> {checking}
11-29 11:37:37.898: I/StorageNotification(336): Media {/storage/sdcard0} state changed from {checking} -> {mounted}
11-29 11:37:38.082: I/ShutdownThread(250): Performing low-level shutdown...
: E/(): Device disconnected
```